# Failed to register task definition in ECS with GitHub Actions CI to AWS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, github-actions

I am setting up a Github Actions CI to AWS Fargate. But facing a permission issue on the step of Deploy Amazon ECS task definition.

Getting the following error:

```
Error: Failed to register task definition in ECS: User: arn:aws:iam::***:user/username is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::***:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole with an explicit deny
Error: User: arn:aws:iam::***:user/username is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::***:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole with an explicit deny
```

I already added below permission to a specific IAM User `arn:aws:iam::***:user/username`. But still does not work

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition",
                "ecs:ListTaskDefinitions",
                "ecs:DescribeTaskDefinition"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::***:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::***:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What if you attach iam:PassRole and sts:AssumeRole policy to the IAM User. That IAM user will only be responsible for assuming the targeted IAM Role ( which in your case is `ecsTaskExecutionRole`) . Create IAM Role with `ecsTaskExecutionRole` and attach all the ECS IAM policy to it.

Comment: I already attached iam:PassRole and sts:AssumeRole policy to that IAM User. but still face the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely reason is some Policy elsewhere explicitly denies you from doing this.

The error message ends with "with an explicit deny" which hints at this:

> Remember, an explicit deny in any of these policies overrides the allow.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html

You should look for the policy in AWS that blocks this grant, your policy itself might be correct.